# Setting up home network with ISP provided router (Sagemcom F@st 5866 5G) and Netgear Nighthawk AX8

Tags: networking, router, internet, wireless-router, home-networking

*I'm aware this question has been asked before, however I would like to ask it again specific to my hardware models.*

*I am technically savvy, but not so much in the networking sense.*

---

I am with TPG as my service provider and have an ISP provided 5G modem/router - Sagemcom F@st 5866 (SF). It has a SIM card that is enabled only for that hardware and provides the internet to the house.

It cannot be put into bridge mode, but I can disable DHCP and WiFi. It has 4 ethernet ports on the back which I have connected Port 2 (just an arbitrary selection), to the Internet port on the Netgear Nighthawk AX8 (NN).

I want to setup the router so that the SF passes internet through the ethernet port to the NN, and the NN handles everything (DHCP, DNS, etc.).

I've played around with it before and got it working where the SF was 192.168.1.1 and the NN was 192.168.2.1 and DHCP was active on both routers, but my Apple HomePod devices and Apple HomeKit kept spazzing out and failing to connect. I think it was due to trying to connect to different networks and not being able to communicate between them. I kept getting notifications in the Apple Home app that HomePods were on the wrong network to what the phone was on, and therefore unable to communicate with the phone.

I just want everything to be able to communicate on the network, as if it was one big network, and I want to keep all the features of the NN and not have it acting as an Access Point only. I want it to be the router. But without the SF having ability to go into Bridge mode, I am struggling to understand how I can do that.

Is this possible?

Unfortunately there is no user manual that I can find for the SF, it's very limited on features and settings, hence I want to limit it as much as possible to just blindly sending internet to the NN.

User manual for the NN [here](https://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/RAX80/RAX80_UM_EN.pdf).

Comment: is there a particular reason for even using the "Sagemcom F@st 5866", what flavour is your NBN? FTTP, FTTB, FTTN, FTTC, HFC?  - I used to be with TPG, and have never used the garbage routers they send

Comment: @JaromandaX unfortunately it’s what provides the 5G internet, and it has a SIM card that’s locked to the hardware. Not NBN.

Comment: Oh, OK - hadn't considered that